# JButton is not responding to mouse click

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, event-listener

This is copied and adapted from the example I received from an earlier question

I have 2 issues at the moment

Firstly, I can only get one JButton to appear on screen, then that JButton is not responding when I press it.
Also, how can I stop the first square from appearing?

I know the program is in one big blob ATM, I will separate into individual classes once I sort these issues out.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class SwingPaintDemo3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI(); 
        }
    });
}

static void createAndShowGUI() {
    System.out.println("Created GUI on EDT? "+
    SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing Paint Demo");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    f.add(new MyPanel());
    f.pack();
    f.setLayout(null);
    JButton seed = new JButton ("Seed");
    seed.setBounds(1050,50,100,50);
    f.add(seed);
    seed.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        System.out.println("Start");
}   
});
    JButton start = new JButton ("Start");
    start.setBounds(1050,150,100,50);
    
    
    f.add(start);
    JButton stop = new JButton ("Stop");
    stop.setBounds(1050,250,100,50);
    //f.add(stop);
    JButton reset = new JButton ("Reset");
    reset.setBounds(1050,350,100,50);
    //f.add(reset);
    f.setVisible(true);
    int lifegrid [] [] [] = new int [42] [62] [2];
    for (int i=0; i<42; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<62; j++) {
            lifegrid [i] [j] [0] = 0;
            lifegrid [i] [j] [1] = 0;
                        }
    }
        } 
}



  class MyPanel extends JPanel {
int lifegrid [] [] [] = new int [62] [42] [2];
int squareX = 0;
int squareY = 0;
int gridX = 0;
int gridY = 0;

public MyPanel() {

          addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            squareX = e.getX();
            squareY = e.getY();
            if ((squareX>50 & squareX<950) & (squareY>50 & squareY <650) ){
                gridX =(squareX-50)/15+1;
                gridY =(squareY-50)/15+1;
                squareX = (squareX -50)/15 * 15 + 50;
                squareY = (squareY -50)/15 * 15 + 50;
                lifegrid [gridX] [gridY] [0] = 1;
                System.out.println(gridX + " " + gridY);
                repaint(squareX,squareY,15,15);}
            else {}
        }
        });
          
               }

public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(1280,800);
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);       
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(squareX,squareY,13,13);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(squareX,squareY,13,13);
}  
}
```

Comment: Which JButton appears? Only one of your JButtons has an action listener. This is really bad though, why are you using a null layout manager? Then you'll have to set your bounds manually on your panel too, not just your buttons.

Comment: Here is what I suggest. A. Left your frame have the default layout manager, which a is a [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/BorderLayout.html). B. Create your MyPanel and add it to the center of the jframe. Eg. `f.add(myPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER)` C. Create a new JPanel for holding your buttons, add your buttons to that JPanel, then `f.add(myButtonPanel, BorderLayout.EAST)` that will essentially setup what you have without having to manually use 'setBounds' on all of your components.

Comment: *I will separate into individual classes once I sort these issues out.*  Separating your code into methods and classes will make testing much easier.

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 buttons.

One button's face reads 'Seed'. When you press it, your action listener will print "Start".

The other button's face reads 'Start'. It has no action listener, therefore, if pressed, nothing happens.

SOURCE: Just.. read your code, it's right there.

I assume that's a bug. If not, that is quite confusing: Why would pressing the button that does *NOT* have 'Start' written on it, print 'Start' to sysout?

You then add both buttons to a panel with dubious layouting.

I assume you're pressing the only button you can see (With 'Start' on it), because it is right on top of the other button, and you observe nothing.

Which is exactly what you programmed.

Probable solutions:

- Fix your layouting, or use a layout manager. Then press the right button (the one that reads 'Seed')
- Add an action listener to your start button and make it print 'start'.
- Fix the bug where clicking the Seed button prints Start. You should make that print 'Seed'.